# While loop is endless because the break point doesn't work

Tags: java, if-statement, breakpoints

I'm trying out the code below but I'm getting a endless loop. The break point doesn't seem to help at all.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter ID Number: ");
        int studentSn = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter your Marks: ");
        int Score = keyboard.nextInt();

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean stop = false;

        String answer = "";
        String Grade = "";
        String msg = "";
        int counter = 0;

        while (!stop) {

            if (Score < 50) {
                Grade = "F";
            } else if (Score <= 64) {
                Grade = "P";
            } else if (Score <= 74) {
                Grade = "C";
            } else if (Score <= 84) {
                Grade = "D";
            } else if (Score <= 100) {
                Grade = "HD";
            } else {
                msg = "Invalid Input";

            }

            if (Grade != null) {
                System.out.println("Student Serial Number: " + studentSn);
                System.out.println("Your Grade is: " + Grade);
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue (yes/no): " + answer);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Student Serial Number: " + studentSn);
                System.out.println(msg);
                System.out.println("Do you want to continue (yes/no): " + answer);
            }

            while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
            {
                counter++;

                if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `stop`? You set it to `false` to start the loop, but then you never change it to `true` so how do you expect the loop to stop?

Comment: Please remove the breakpoint tag; that refers to the concept of a breakpoint in a debugger, not the `break` in your loop.

Answer (score 4):

There are multiple infinite loops in this scenario. With

```
while (!stop) {
   // ...
}
```

you never set "stop" to true, meaning that the loop would end. The break statement in

```
while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
{
    counter++;

    if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
        break;
    }
}
```

would only break out of that loop, not the `!stop` loop. If you wanted to break out of both loops, you'd need to do

```
MY_LABEL: while (!stop) {
    // ...
    while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
    {
        counter++;

        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
            break MY_LABEL;
    }
}
```

or otherwise write `stop = true;` at some point. However, that is not the only endless loop in your code. In

```
while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
{
     // loop body                     ^ problem here
}
```

your loop statement is followed by a semicolon! This should be

```
while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
{
     // loop body 
}
```

since your code right now is the same as writing

```
while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
    ; // do nothing
// loop body
```

because of how Java's syntax works. Your current code compiles because you can have a block without any loops or if statements

```
// do some stuff
{ // begin new scope
    int x = 10;
} // end scope
int y = x; // error because x is not in scope!
```

but this is clearly not what you intended.

Beyond that, you never read anything into `answer` meaning it always equals `""`-- it never equals "YES" or "NO" at all! At least somewhere you should be saying

```
answer = scan.nextLine();
```

to read input.

The entire program is a bit wonky though. Here's how I would lay it out:

```
// Instead of using "stop", we can just break out of the loop when we're done
while(true) {
    // ...

    // Prompt for input. I use "print" instead of "println" so that the user's answer will be on the same line as the question, e.g.
    // Do you want to continue (yes/no): YES
    // instead of
    // Do you want to continue (yes/no):
    // YES
    // and so forth
    System.out.print("Do you want to continue (yes/no): ");
    // This is how we actually read input.
    String answer = scan.nextLine();

    // If the user doesn't say "YES" (this could be "NO" or "q" or "asdf" or anything else), break out of the loop
    if(!answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
        break;
}
```

I think you're a bit confused about how loops and input work. Just because you write `System.out.println("my question: " + answer)` doesn't mean that Java will read the rest of the line into `answer`. It'll actually write whatever is already in `answer`, for example

```
answer = "abc"
System.out.println("Question? " + answer);
// "Question? abc" will be printed, and no input will be read
// answer still equals "abc"
```

and additionally, if you want to ask a question repeatedly, you have to put all of that questioning into the loop. Java will not read anything new into `answer` until you `readLine()` again, so I think that's where the confusion about the while loop comes from. In your `answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES")` loop, nothing new will be read unless you put `answer = scan.readLine()` in it.

Comment: Hi James, appreciate your time replying to my queries. I'm still pretty confuse since I'm really new to Java :( Do you think you can show me a example on how it's suppose to be done?

Comment: @HowardD I've edited my answer with an example, and added a bit of explanation based on what I think you might be confused about. If you need further clarification, I can try to explain further. If you understand it now, consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have two while loops going on, your attempt to break has not been executed correctly, is only exiting the inner loop.

Let strip your loop logic back to only describing the variables and logic that will affect the loop itself: I have replaced your other code with method calls to simplify the demo, assume that you already implemented these methods and that they do what the names infer.

> This is a good technique for transitioning form pseudo code to actual code but just as useful for evaluating loop constructs that aren't going the way you planned

```
int studentSn = ReadInt("Enter ID Number: ");
int Score = ReadInt("Enter your Marks: ");
string answer = "";
boolean stop = false;
while(!stop) { // this is never ending, nothing ever sets stop to true
    Grade = DetermineGrade(score);
    if (Grade != null) {
        ShowGrade(studentSn, Grade);
        answer = ReadContinuePrompt();
    } else {
        ShowError(studentSn, "Invalid Input");
        answer = ReadContinuePrompt();
    }

    while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"));
    {
        counter++;

        if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) {
            break;
        }
        // If this user's input was not NO, then this loop is infinite and should run into a stack overflow error when the value of counter exceeds the max value of int
    }
}
```

Your outer loop is based on a stop variable:

```
while (!stop)
```

So inside your loop logic, instead of using a break statement, all you need to do is set the value of stop to true. A carefully placed break statement could also do this, but coding a deliberate stop parameter the way you have is a good design that makes the intent very clear.

Now your inner loop is just wrong, I don't want to over analyse it, because you ask for the user input outside of the loop, there is no way to change the answer. So lets replace the inner loop with a simple conditional statement

```
    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) 
        stop = true; // or break;
    else
        counter++;
```

Now we need to go back to how you have coded your outer loop. Again, because the main input is outside of the loop, there is no amount of times with this code where we can say "YES" that will give a different answer, we need to ask the score input inside the loop so the result can be changed

That now gives us this logic:

```
int studentSn = ReadInt("Enter ID Number: ");
string answer = "";
boolean stop = false;
while(!stop) { 
    // read the score inside the loop.
    int Score = ReadInt("Enter your Marks: ");
    Grade = DetermineGrade(score);
    if (Grade != null) {
        ShowGrade(studentSn, Grade);
        answer = ReadContinuePrompt();
    } else {
        ShowError(studentSn, "Invalid Input");
        answer = ReadContinuePrompt();
    }

    if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase("NO")) 
        stop = true; // or break;
    else
        counter++;
}
```